# How to workaround "Contains" for .net 3.5 don't support

Tags: entity-framework, .net-3.5, linq-to-entities

I write a linq to Entity:

```
string[] groups = GetGroups();
                var fList = from f in _store.wcf_ServerFarm
                               join a in _store.ClientAccess on f.ServerFarmName equals a.AccessServerFarmName
                               join s in _store.Service on f.ServerFarmName equals s.ServerFarmName
                               where groups.Contains(s.ServerMachineName)
                               select new { f.ServerFarmAddress, s.ServerMachineName, s.ServiceName, s.ServiceConfig, s.ServicePath };
```

But .net 3.5 didn't support Contains(), I couldn't upgrade it for some reason. how to figure out it. I try to use "Any(), esql" and so on ,didn't work.
Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88473/how-to-do-a-where-in-values-in-linq-to-entities-3-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/) is described workaround with building custom expression. Internally it builds a query concatenating a lot of `OR` operators. No better workaround is probably available for LINQ in EFv1. [Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386895%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) should work without problem.

Comment: But my Query included 2 "join" sentences , it's really hard to use this solution.

Comment: That is the burden of Entity Framework alpha version (aka EFv1)